# AutoTextComplete dropdown menu not working in fragment

Tags: android

[image: gif of issue]

I'm attempting to implement a dropdown menu using the material AutoCompleteTextView.  I've implemented it and from all the searching I've done, I believe it should work, but it doesnt.  My Dialog Fragment is being rendered with another fragment, not sure if that is the problem.  The only thing I can think is that I have not set up the adapter correctly or something, any ideas or feedback?  Sorry I tried to post XML but stackoverflow couldnt handle, even after using  http://wittman.org/projects/stackoverflowindentfourspaces/

```
Code in Dialog fragment
```

```
import android.app.Dialog
import android.content.Context
import android.content.DialogInterface
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment
import android.view.MenuInflater
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView


class AddBillFragment: DialogFragment() {


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {

        var rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_bill,container,false)
        var autoCompleteTextView: AutoCompleteTextView? = view?.findViewById(R.id.autoComplete)
        val options: Array<String> = arrayOf("option1", "option2")
        val arrayAdapter = getActivity()?.let { ArrayAdapter<String>(it.getApplicationContext(), 
        R.layout.add_bill_type_items,options) }
        autoCompleteTextView?.setAdapter(arrayAdapter)
        return rootView
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be using `rootView` instead of `view` here. You're in the middle of creating the view hierarchy in `onCreateView` so `view` can't be anything yet.

Comment: As a side note, this might be a good time to learn how to debug a program with the debugger. If you step through your code line by line it makes it much easier to see the state of the variables. You also might want to consider your choice of `?` here. For example, `getActivity()` should never be null so you should probably assert that it isn't.

Answer (score 1):

In `onCreateView()`, `getView()` (`view` in Kotlin) will return `null`, so you're not able to get a reference to the autocomplete view.

Move the creation of the adapter and the setting of it into `onViewCreated()` and your code should work.